# Aligning in defining functions

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, split

Very often, I want to write functions like this

`$f: X\to Y, x\mapsto y$`

so that they align. I try to use the align environment but this gives rather inappropriate spacing or alignment.

For example,

```
\begin{align}
f:& X&\to& Y\\
&x&\mapsto& y\\
\end{align}
```

Gives the wrong alignment.

```
\begin{align}
f:& X&&\to&& Y\\
&x&&\mapsto&& y\\
\end{align}
```

gives the wrong spacing. (There is too much space between the arrow and the letters.

What's the correct use of ampersand that would give a reasonable spacing and alignment? If there are alternatives to the align environment (`aligned`, `split`, etc) that would also be very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`align` has a `R&L` (`R`/`L` = `R`ight/`L`eft alignment) with a single `&`. With multiple elements, the alignments are `R&L & R&L & R&L...` with the "middle" `&` adding addition space. So, your use

```
\begin{align}
f:& X&\to& Y\\
&x&\mapsto& y\\
\end{align}
```

can be rewritten visually to highlight the spacing/alignment as

```
\begin{align}
  f: & X    &        \to & Y \\
     & x    &    \mapsto & y
\end{align}
```

Here are some alternatives:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  f \colon X&   \to   Y \\
           x& \mapsto y
\end{align*}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
    f \colon &&   X &   \to{}   && YYY \\
             && xxx & \mapsto{} && y
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

It depends on the specific alignment you're after.